# Sequelize-typescript include on Many to Many only includes one of many results

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship between Users and Tags that may describe them, and to include an array of a users Tags when fetching the user. The problem is that only one of many associated Tags is included in the User object.

I assume there is a simple problem with my code but to me it looks just like I'm following the example on docs. All other includes with one-to-many or one-to-one associations work just fine.

**tag.model.ts**

```
@DefaultScope({ attributes: ['text', 'color'] })
@Table({
    paranoid: true,
    timestamps: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'tags',
})
export default class Tag extends Model<Tag> {
    // ...
    @BelongsToMany(() => User, () => UserTag)
    users!: User[];
}
```

**user.model.ts**

```
@Table({
    paranoid: true,
    timestamps: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'users'
})
export default class User extends Model<User> {
    // ...
    @BelongsToMany(() => Tag, () => UserTag)
    tags!: Tag[];
}
```

**usertag.model.ts**

```
@Table({
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'user_tags'
})
export default class UserTag extends Model<UserTag> {
    @ForeignKey(() => User)
    @Column
    user_id!: number;

    @ForeignKey(() => Tag)
    @Column
    tag_id!: number;
}
```

**sequelize.config.ts**

```
// ...
User.addScope('public', {
    include: [
        // ...
        { model: Tag, as: 'tags', through: { attributes: [] } },
    ]
} as IFindOptions<User>);
```

When calling

```
User.scope('public').findByPk( ... )
```

the returned object includes only the first Tag for example

```
"tags": [
            {
                "text": "Cool Guy",
                "color": "#002B36"
            }
        ],
```

when in the database there exist many more tags

```
1, Cool Guy, #002B36
2, New Tag, #00FF00 ...
```

and more user tags (user_id, tag_id)

```
1, 1
1, 2 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When posting this question I simplified the code to remove the bulk of the models columns and such that were obviously irrelevant to the question, but I also neglected to include that the Tags have a DefaultScope limiting their attributes to 'name' and 'color'. The problem was that this does not include the primary key, 'id' in this case.

Simply adding 'id' to the default scope fixed the issue. Oops.